# Spring Security authorize in REST (or form-login) app by HTTP GET

Tags: authentication, spring-security, spring-boot, get

I'm writing backend app based on Spring Boot without any views (templates), because client app will use it's own HTML.
I'm trying change default behavior (HTTP `POST`) Spring Security `form-login` authentication - use HTTP `GET` and `POST`. Yes, I know, it's bad for security, but it's requirement.
How I can do it?

My app:
Application

```java
package net.company.rest;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```java
package net.company.rest.config;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    // configure security
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);

        http.formLogin().usernameParameter("user").passwordParameter("pass");
        http.formLogin().successHandler(authSuccessHandler).failureHandler(authFailureHandler);

        http.logout().permitAll();

        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    // enable security
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user" + i).password("user" + i).roles("USER");
        }
    }
}
```

AuthEntryPoint

```java
package net.company.rest.component;

@Component
public class AuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest req,
                     HttpServletResponse resp,
                     AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException {

        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        UniversalMessage msg = new UniversalMessage(1, "not authenticated");
        try {
            resp.getWriter().print(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(msg));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            resp.getWriter().print(e.toString());
        }
        resp.getWriter().flush();
    }
}
```

AuthSuccessHandler

```java
package net.company.rest.component;

@Component
public class AuthSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse resp,
                                    Authentication auth) throws ServletException, IOException {

        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        UniversalMessage msg = new UniversalMessage(0, "auth success");
        try {
            resp.getWriter().print(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(msg));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            resp.getWriter().print(e.toString());
        }
        resp.getWriter().flush();
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(req);
    }
}
```

AuthFailureHandler

```java
package net.company.rest.component;
@Component
public class AuthFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse resp,
                                    AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException {

        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        UniversalMessage msg = new UniversalMessage(1, "auth error");
        try {
            resp.getWriter().print(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(msg));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            resp.getWriter().print(e.toString());
        }
        resp.getWriter().flush();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that above code didn't solve problem, `login` by `HTTP GET` didn't work anyway.
There is steps for solve:

1. Add new class extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

```java
package net.company.rest.config.web;

@Slf4j
public class AuthByGetFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public AuthByGetFilter() {
        super();
        // change auth parameters
        setUsernameParameter("user");
        setPasswordParameter("pass");

        // allow GET
        setPostOnly(false);
        setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "GET"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {

        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

        log.debug("Method: {}, Request: {}, params was hidden for security", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL());

        log.debug("Authentication request failed: {}", failed.toString());
        log.debug("Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication");
        log.debug("Delegating to authentication failure handler " + getFailureHandler());

        getRememberMeServices().loginFail(request, response);
        getFailureHandler().onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, failed);

    }

}
```

2. Use this class as filter in the above described `SecurityConfig` class

```java
...

// configure security
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(authByGetFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); // add authByGetFilter
    ...
}

// allow authentication by http GET method
@Bean
public AuthByGetFilter authByGetFilter() throws Exception {
    AuthByGetFilter authByGetFilter = new AuthByGetFilter();
    authByGetFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    authByGetFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authFailureHandler);
    authByGetFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authSuccessHandler);
    return authByGetFilter;
}

...
```